# White MaterialShapeDrawable is Gray upon elevation

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin, material-components-android

I currently have FrameLayout with the following code upon initialization in its init function

```
            val bgDrawable = MaterialShapeDrawable.createWithElevationOverlay(context).apply {
                fillColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE)
            }
            ViewCompat.setBackground(this, bgDrawable)
```

When the elevation is 0, the background renders correctly white

However, when I set the elevation to greater than 0, the background becomes gray.

Somethings that I tried was setting the tint to white, but, that seems to get rid of the elevation shadow of the `MaterialShapeDrawable`

Goal:
I just want a White MaterialShapeDrawable background value on a `FrameLayout` and when elevation is > 0, to stay white with the elevation shadow intact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends by the [elevation overlay](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md#elevation-overlays) color and it happens only if the current theme's attribute **`elevationOverlayEnabled`** is `true` and the `backgroundColor` (`fillColor`) matches the theme's surface color (`colorSurface` attribute).

If you want to avoid this behavior you can set in your app theme:

```
<item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
```

Check in particolar way the app theme in the dark mode where this attribute is `true` by default.